# how to implement 2 timers that run at the same time

Tags: c#

I got a timer that is working perfectly, I am wondering if I can just add a second timer and have it run at the same time, but different intervals. I am attempting to stay away from scheduled tasks.

To Clarify:

I have one timer that connects to a remote service every 30 minutes or so, that runs on a timer elapsed event.

however I need a second timer that fires every 24 hours or once a day.

It's a backup system basically, that has an "incremental" and daily feature.

Comment: Why would you want two timers to fire at the exact same time as apposed to just one timer that does two things?

Comment: Clarify "at the same time". With different intervals they won't stay synced very long.

Comment: By "at the same time" do you mean concurrently or do you mean intervals overlapping somehow? What exact class do you use for timer? If it is not WinForms timer than you can have 2 instances of timer running concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically: yes. But keep in mind they are probably (depending on your code) running on the same thread. So they don't execute at the same moment.

This also means that short-timer-interval, and long handle time, could give some issues.

Comment: The second timer won't start **exactly** when the first one starts when your computer has only one core and one CPU.

Comment: @Alireza: True. I am assuming the OP is using a default C# timer, if so he/she wont get (and probably doesn't need) a better accuracy of +/- 30 ms. High performance timers are a complete different subject :)